# Creating Custom JSF 1.2 Components

Tags: java, jsf

We are migrating some of our custom components from JSF 1.1 to 1.2.  We have one component (a date selector) which extends HtmlInputText component.  We are getting a JSP error when trying to use a validator with this component.  Our tag class extends HtmlInputTag (most of the examples online I've read extend UIComponentELTag, so not sure if this is a problem).  The component works fine until we add ' validator="..." ' at which point we get a JSP compilation problem.  Looking for any suggestions on what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with the OP (user502058) and just wanted to follow up on the solution to this issue. We undid the "fix" posted earlier related to the the tag class ancestry - our custom component tag class extends HTMLInputTag. I ended up copying the entire  entry for the standard inputText component from the JSF 1.2 TLDs and added the 5 attributes related to our custom component. This resolved the problem. There was something missing in the TLD and that's what was causing the compilation error. I didn't have time to sift through all attributes and pinpoint the root cause, but it's working fine now.